# Prove that Minimum Vertex Cover problem is dual to Maximum matching problems

Tags: linear-programming

So, I'm able to formulate both linear programming problems like this:

---

I have a graph G ={V,E}.

**Minimum Vertex Cover:**

$$
min \sum_{v \in V} x_v\\
x_{v_i} + x_{v_j} \geq 1, (\forall e = (v_i, v_j) \in E)\\
x_v \in \left\{0;1\right\}
$$

where $x_{v_i} = 1$ when the vertex $v_i$ belongs to the cover and otherwise.

**Maximum matching:**

$$
max \sum_{e \in E} x_e\\
\forall v \in V: \sum_{e \sim v}x_e \leq 1\\
\forall e \in E: x_e \in \{0;1\}
$$

where $v \sim e$ means incidence of the vertex $v$ and the edge $e$ and $x_e = 1$ when the edge $e$ belong to the maximum matching and otherwise.

---

But how can I show, that these two are dual problems?